# Azure Mobile App framework with Android (Kotlin only)

Tags: android, azure, kotlin, azure-mobile-services, azure-sdk

Is it possible to work with Azure Mobile App Service framework on Android app with Kotlin code only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Azure Mobile Apps SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library) mentions only Java, but you should be able to replace all Java code with Kotlin since both compile to JVM bytecode.